# Stack copies of elements of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a vector that has `N=1263` entries:

```
temp=[14, 0.5, ..., 12]
```

I want to make a vector which repeats entry 1, i.e. `14`, 42 times, then entry 2, i.e. `0.5`, 42 times and similarly all through the vector. It should produce a vector with size 53046x1.

The following code does the work for a simple case:

```
F = [1 4 9];
R = [repmat(F(1),[3,1]); repmat(F(2),[3,1]); repmat(F(3),[3,1])]    
R = [1 1 1 4 4 4 9 9 9]
```

but it is cumbersome when `N` becomes large. Is there a faster way around this?

Comment: Try this way: R = repmat(F(:)', 3, 1); R = R(:);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what [**`repelem`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) (introduced in R2015a) is for. For your actual problem, you would use:

```
R = repelem(temp.',42);  %This will repeat each entry of 'temp' 42 times
```

For the given example,

```
F = [1 4 9];
R = repelem(F.',3);      %This will repeat each entry of 'F' 3 times
```

---

You can also do it with this:

```
R = ones(42,1)*temp;
R = R(:);
```

Comment: Also (for Matlab versions without `repelem`): `F = [1 4 9]; n = 3; R = F(ceil(1/n:1/n:end))`

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an unusual way of doing this but it works

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html

All you need to do is include your matrix as well as a ones matrix of the length of the repetition.

```
R = kron(F(:),ones(42,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
R = reshape(repmat(F, 42, 1), [], 1);
```